# sql -- issue with repeat values on join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL. I think it maybe due to an issue of my PK/FK or my lack of understanding of how to query properly:

```
CREATE TABLE Minute
(
Name  varchar(20),
Day date,
Minute time,
Weight real
Speed real
PRIMARY KEY (Name, Day, Minute)
) 
--NOTE: This table has everyday, for every minute in a month.
CREATE TABLE DataMan
(
Name   varchar(20),
Day    date,  --NOTE: This is by day 10/31/2013, 11/31/2013
Size   real,
Volume real,
NumEv  real,
PRIMARY KEY (Name, Day)
)
```

The kind of data that I have in DataMan would be like:

```
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 123 | 456 | 5
GOOG | 11/31/2013 | 234 | 412 | 5
```

and with a bunch of other names and data with months.

The kind of data that I have in Minute would be like:

```
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 12:00:00 | 251.312 | 1231.12
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 12:01:00 | 124.51 | 1239
```

So, I want to create table where it has:

```
Minute.Name | Minute.Date | Minute.Time | DataMan.Size
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 12:00:00 | 123
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 12:01:00 | 123
```

This is my query

```
 SELECT minute.name, minute.date, minute.time, dataman.size
 FROM minute LEFT JOIN dataman ON (minute.name = dataman.name)
 ORDER BY minute.name ASC, minute.date ASC, minute.time ASC
```

And what happens is that the table output does something like:

```
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 12:00:00 | 123
GOOG | 10/31/2013 | 12:00:00 | 234
```

I want the Dataman.size to remain the same by the increment of minutes, but it seems to do a cartesian product and put every value of Dataman.size on the minute time frame, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just forgot to join on `Day` in addition to `Name`.

In the join condition, instead of:

```
ON (minute.name = dataman.name)
```

this should be:

```
ON (minute.name = dataman.name AND minute.Day=dataman.Day)
```

Since there's a unique constraint on (name,day) in `dataman`, we know that only one row of `dataman` will match for every row in `minute`, with the above join condition.

Comment: For my purposes, the issue would be that the JOIN would only match certain days because the minute.Day (everyday) has a higher granularity of days then the dataman (one a month). I would want it so that postgres would just leave the last known value. So there would be repating values throughout the month until the dataman changes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent size from `dataman` before or on the date in the `minute` table.  Is this interpretation correct?

Here is one way of getting it with a correlated subquery:

```
 SELECT minute.name, minute.date, minute.time,
        (select dataman.size
         from dataman
         where minute.name = dataman.name and
               minute.date >= dataman.date
         limit 1
        ) as size
 FROM minut
 ORDER BY minute.name ASC, minute.date ASC, minute.time ASC
```